# Simple Linear Transform Algorithm not working

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

```
__global__ 
void transpose(double *input, double *output, int *width, int *height) 
{
    int threadidx = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    int row = threadidx / (*width);
    int column = (threadidx+3) % (*height);
    output[column * (*height) + row] = input[threadidx];
}
```

Above is my kernel for linear transformations. For an input matrix of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] the output matrix should be [0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8], but when I run this code using the aforementioned example, the output is [0, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. I've written a serial implementation of the algorithm in Python, and it works. The only thing I can think of is some sort of thread memory access problem. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: The error is occurring somewhere in code you are not showing us. Please edit your question to include the shortest possible complete example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Try using cuda-memcheck. But I tried the above code with example it works fine. There is no problem with the above code. U may want to show the full code to help.

Comment: If you have to do a parallel transposition, I recall that the CUDA SDK contain a `transpose` example.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have already pointed out, your code happens to work correctly for the sample input case you have identified:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

And if you are not getting the results you have indicated, then the error is outside of the code you have shown.  However, it appears you are trying to transpose an array.

This code will not work for the general case (e.g. try a 2x2 array: `[0, 1, 2, 3]`)

This line of code in particular isn't right, if your intention is to transpose an array:

```
    int column = (threadidx+3) % (*height);
```

If you change it to:

```
    int column = (threadidx) % (*width);
```

Your code will produce a correct transpose result for various matrix sizes.